# "Renders with edge antialiasing" Makes UIViews look worse with transform

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, antialiasing

I have some UIViews which have a transform with both translation and rotation and they were looking aliased so I turned on "Renders with edge antialiasing" in -Info.plist and it actually makes it look worse!

Instead of just being jaggy, they also seem to have black mixed in to the jaggy edges. There is a shadow, but the layer behind it is not black.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I found a lot of different advice on this, but it seems that "Renders with edge antialiasing" doesn't do a lot in the grand scheme of things. However, it helps a little extra with the solution I found below:

```
self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
self.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

These 2 lines go on my UIView that gets transformed which is just a layer with [UIColor clearColor] as the background. Anything with colors or images or any content is a subview. Otherwise, with the rounded corners I'm using, I saw a little black on the edges.